# Unable to automate crontab

Tags: python, django, cron

I have a django project which utilizes a function notify_about_changes to send email to users about the history of objects for the last week in a table format. It works fine when it happens manually through

```
$python manage.py shell
```

To automate the job I looked into [Django-Kronos](http://django-kronos) and configuring the crontab as below:-

```
$sudo crontab -e
*1 * * * * pathto/venv/python3.4 pathto/manage.py notify_about_changes
$sudo cron restart
```

Problem:- crontab doesnot work its raising issues like reponse failed from my ipaddress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a typo but your crontab looks like it has an errant initial asterisk. It should be:

```
1 * * * * pathto/venv/python3.4 pathto/manage.py notify_about_changes
```

That will run the script at one minute past every hour, which is probably not what you want for a weekly task. Instead you might want to try:

```
0 0 * * 0 pathto/venv/python3.4 pathto/manage.py notify_about_changes
```

which will run your job every Sunday at midnight.

Answer (score 0):

This may not directly answer your question, but I had a hard time using cron too with Django, and then I switched to using `APScheduler` which is flexible as compared to cron. It has a cron style scheduler:

[Cronschedule | APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.2/cronschedule.html)

The main advantage of `APScheduler` as compared to similar modules like `cron` and `celery` is that schedules can be dynamically changed without having to restart the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

When your application is being called from Cron, it will "capture" and handle all the information your application  generates to the system.

I don't know exactly this module you are using, but I believe one of the following will solve your problem:

1- Configure Cron to send the logging files to a specific file.

2- Change the sys.stderr and  sys.stdout  to a specific configuration, like a terminal, shell, -app, etc

3- Configure the logging module to correct all information.